# How do i get properties from cmdlet commands and save them as a integers to a variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

for example, I am trying to get a value from a cmdlet save it as int and use it in an if statement or while statement in a PowerShell script.

$value = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType = '2'"  | Select-Object Size
echo $value

```
 Size
 ----
1992032256 <------- I am trying to get that number so that I can use it in a if statement and compare it with another number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType = '2'"` statement is likely to return more than just one object.
To compare the Size properties to some value, you need to iterate over the result(s):

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType = '2'" | ForEach-Object {
    # for demo, output to console if the Size is greater or equal then 16 GB
    $sizeGB = [math]::Round($_.Size / 1GB)  # Size is an Int64 value in Bytes
    if ($sizeGB -ge 16) {
        Write-Host "Drive $($_.DeviceID) has a total capacity of $sizeGB GB"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
$value = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType = '2'"
$value.size
```